# how to input client ID or API key in distance Matrix Google API Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get shortest distance between two locations using google Distance Matrix API. To get shortest distance I am passing OPTIMISTIC parameter to trafficModel. To make it work I have to pass client ID or API key. I have both. I don't know how to pass this API key to DistanceMatrixService. Please suggest any ways to achieve this.

js file

```
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();  
service.getDistanceMatrix({
  origins: ["A","B"],
  destinations: ["A","B"],

  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  drivingOptions: {
     departureTime: new Date(moment().tz(gUserTimeZone).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A')+400), 

     trafficModel :google.maps.TrafficModel.OPTIMISTIC
    },
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false,
 },function(response){console.log(response);});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/distance-matrix), the credentials are [included in the API load](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).

You can use either set of credentials.